# DocuSign: Getting a list of all documents a user has access to

Tags: c#, asp.net, docusignapi

We are updating an application to allow users to upload/attach files directly from various external sources (DocuSign, Drop Box, Google Drive, etc). I am currently trying to get a list of all files a user has access to in their DocuSign account. I am working in C# with the DocuSign .NET REST API library (DocuSign.eSign.dll).

I can get as far as authenticating as the user and getting their default account id. I am trying to use the FoldersApi.Search method but I get a "404 - File or directory not found error". Can someone familiar with DocuSign review my code and tell me what I might be doing wrong?

```
var apiClient = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");

var code = Request["Code"];
var token = apiClient.GenerateAccessToken(IntegratorKey, SecretKey, code);

var userInfo = DocuSignClient.GetUserInfo(token.access_token);
var accountId = "";
foreach (var account in userInfo.Accounts) {
    if (account.IsDefault == "true") {
        accountId = account.AccountId;
        apiClient = new ApiClient(account.BaseUri);
        break;
    }
}

var configuration =
    new Configuration(apiClient: apiClient, accessToken: token.access_token);

var foldersApi = new FoldersApi(configuration);
var response = foldersApi.Search(accountId, "all");
foreach (var folder in response.FolderItems) {
    Context.Response.Write(folder.FolderId);
}
```

Comment: I just posted an answer that might resolve your issue, give it a try and let me know.  Thx

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: I've never used DocuSign before. But having looked at the REST API and the .NET client I've come up with a possible solution.

It looks like you're using the folders search incorrectly. The signature for that API is as follows:

```
public FolderItemResponse Search (string accountId, string searchFolderId, FoldersApi.SearchOptions options = null)
```

Where the valid values for the `searchFolderId` are `drafts`, `awaiting_my_signature`, `completed`, or `out_for_signature`, but you've provided `all` which is the one of the **search options** not one of the **search folder IDs**.

The correct usage would be something like this:

```
var response = foldersApi.Search(accountId, "completed", FoldersApi.SearchOptions.all);
```

where you would replace `completed` with whatever value it is you need from the valid values I've mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately it didn't help, still getting the same 404 message.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see an issue with your code though not in a good place to test currently, hopefully you can confirm soon.  On the first line you correctly instantiate an API Client for demo environment with:

```
var apiClient = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
```

However after authenticating and getting their user info, you then re-configure the base path with:

```
apiClient = new ApiClient(account.BaseUri);
```

I believe this might be leading to the 404 error because this will only contain the domain.  In other words, this has the effect of doing:

```
apiClient = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net");
```

You need to add the remaining `/restapi/v2/{accountId}` to form the proper base request URL, try something like this instead:

```
apiClient = new ApiClient(account.BaseUri + "/restapi/v2/accounts/" + accountId);
```

### --------------------------------

**UPDATE**

Just did some testing and got things to work however note that I'm using Node.js not C#.  Still should be same logic though.  Here's my working code for getting all completed envelopes:

```
docusign.Configuration.default.setDefaultApiClient(apiClient);

var foldersApi = new docusign.FoldersApi(docusign.Configuration.default.getDefaultApiClient());
foldersApi.search(accountId, "completed")
    .then(function(response) { 
        console.log("response = " + JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
        return null;
    })
    .catch(function (error){
    if (error) {
      console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
      return error;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and you were correct I did need to append “/restapi” onto the account.BaseUri. I didn’t see that in the code samples I had found. Interesting enough that just brings me back to the sandbox URL I start with ("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi").   

Unfortunately now I just get a new error message. 
    errorCode: PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
    message: The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified.

Comment: Sorry I forgot that you also need the rest API version and account info in the URL... I've updated my answer please give it another go as pretty sure this should finally resolve.  Basically you just need to change that line to:  `apiClient = new ApiClient(account.BaseUri + "/restapi/v2/accounts/" + accountId);`

Comment: Well that got me a new error message at least. With your suggested changed I now get the following error:

"DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException: Error calling Search: at DocuSign.eSign.Api.FoldersApi.SearchWithHttpInfo(String accountId, String searchFolderId, SearchOptions options)"

Comment: I think that means your URL is now correct and now you're getting more of a semantic error related to the API itself.  I got this working and posted my code however I'm in node unfortunately (sorry don't have a C# box right now)

Comment: The only thing I can really see different from your JavaScript example is that you call `docusign.Configuration.default.setDefaultApiClient(apiClient);`. I tried the equivalent in C# `DocuSign.eSign.Client.Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;` and it did not change the error code that I get.